# The following artifacts could not be resolved: javax.jms:jms:jar:1.1

Tags: maven-2, jar, sun

I am trying to compile a maven project, but I systematically get the following error message:

```
[ERROR]Failed to execute goal on project ...:
Could not resolve dependencies for project ...:war:1.0.0:
The following artifacts could not be resolved: javax.jms:jms:jar:1.1,
com.sun.jdmk:jmxtools:jar:1.2.1, com.sun.jmx:jmxri:jar:1.2.1:
Failure to find javax.jms:jms:jar:1.1 in http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/maven2/
  was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until
  the update interval of maven2-repository.ibiblio.mirror has elapsed or
  updates are forced -> [Help 1]
```

I know about [this maven post about Sun jars](http://khmarbaise.github.io/maven-site/reflow/guides/mini/guide-coping-with-sun-jars.html), but it does not solve the problem.

Is there a repository I can specify in my `pom.xml`?

Answer (score 86, accepted):

Thanks for the suggestions. I finally found a solution to this problem after reading [this](http://www.mail-archive.com/log4j-dev@logging.apache.org/msg07530.html). It turns out that these dependencies were coming from a dependency to ZooKeeper.

I modified my pom.xml as following and it solved the problem:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.zookeeper</groupId>
        <artifactId>zookeeper</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.2</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Good workaround.  I had the same problem today with a log4j dependency.  It looks like https://maven-repository.dev.java.net/nonav/repository has an invalid cert perhaps (Chrome gives me a big warning when I hit that url). That's the server those deps are hosted at I think.

Comment: I get an SSL cert warning as well, but came to realize that it was because the domain does not exist.  It was because of OpenDNS and their default fallback page.

Comment: It looks like transient dependency `log4j:log4j:1.2.15` is pulling in those odd dependencies. Excluding log4j from the zookeeper dependency, and including a newer version of log4j yourself also seems to solve this problem.

Comment: @JamesCooper Check this(http://unitstep.net/blog/2009/05/18/resolving-log4j-1215-dependency-problems-in-maven-using-exclusions/) out. It explains the log4j issue.

Answer (score 67):

If anyone still wants to use jms1.1 then add the public jboss repository and maven will find it...

project->dependencies:

```
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
      <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
      <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

project->repositories:

```
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>repository.jboss.org-public</id>
      <name>JBoss.org Maven repository</name>
      <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
    </repository>
```

It works -

```
F:\mvn-repo-stuff>mvn verify
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building mvn-repo-stuff 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax/jms/jms/1.1/jms-1.1.pom
Downloaded: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax/jms/jms/1.1/jms-1.1.pom (677 B at 0.8 KB/sec)
[WARNING] The artifact xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:2.0.2 has been relocated to xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.0.b2
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax/jms/jms/1.1/jms-1.1.jar
Downloading: https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/javax/jms/jms/1.1/jms-1.1.jar
Downloaded: https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/javax/jms/jms/1.1/jms-1.1.jar (26 KB at 8.5 KB/sec)
```

Comment: I found it only in the repository: https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/thirdparty-releases/

Comment: Do you put this in <repositories> section? It didn't help in my case.

Comment: I placed the repository in the User Settings settings.xml, but it didn't do the job for me either.

Comment: For me its was giving this error.Could not find artifact org.jboss.com.sun.httpserver:httpserver:jar:1.0.0.Final in java.net...... When i change the repository to jboss its downloaded now .. thanks

Answer (score 24):

Log4 version 1.2.17 automatically resolves the issue as it has depency on geronimo-jms. I got the same issue with log4j- 1.2.15 version.

---

Added with more around the issue

---

using 1.2.17 resolved the issue during the compile time but the server(Karaf) was using 1.2.15 version thus creating conflict at run time. Thus I had to switch back to 1.2.15.

The JMS and JMX api were available for me at the runtime thus i did not import the J2ee api.

what i did was I used the compile time dependency on 1.2.17 but removed it at the runtime.

```
            <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>
....
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <instructions>
                        <Bundle-SymbolicName>${project.groupId}.${project.artifactId}</Bundle-SymbolicName>
                                                          <Import-Package>!org.apache.log4j.*,*</Import-Package>

.....
```

Answer (score 15):

Another solution if you don't want to modify your settings:

Download [jms-1.1.jar from JBoss repository](https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/javax/jms/jms/1.1/jms-1.1.jar) then:

`mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=javax.jms -DartifactId=jms -Dversion=1.1 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=jms-1.1.jar`

Comment: it worked all the way to compile project. thanks. One question: if I delete the .m2 folder, I have to again issue this command. am I right?

Comment: if I delete the .m2 folder, I have to again issue this command?  << Yes you do. mvn install will copy an artifact to your local mvn repo.

Answer (score 5):

In fact the real solution for this issue is to use the jms-api-1.1-rev-1.jar artifact available on Maven Central : http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Cjavax.jms%7Cjms-api%7C1.1-rev-1%7Cjar

Comment: I think this is the best solution in case your projects depends on JMS. This way you delegate to Maven the resolution of JMS too, as one would ideally expect.

Comment: Easy, simple solution. No need to add a new repository.

Answer (score 3):

Try forcing updates using the mvn `cpu` option:

```
usage: mvn [options] [<goal(s)>] [<phase(s)>]

Options:
 -cpu,--check-plugin-updates            Force upToDate check for any
                                        relevant registered plugins
```

Comment: Its not so good to use -cpu. Here is why "Command line option -cpu is deprecated and will be removed in future Maven versions."

Answer (score 3):

I also faced the same issue when I started using following maven dependency version for log4j (1.2.15) in my project.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>log4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
  <version>1.2.15</version>
</dependency>
```

Following error was thrown at me.

```
The following artifacts could not be resolved: javax.jms:jms:jar:1.1, com.sun.jdmk:jmxtools:jar:1.2.1, com.sun.jmx:jmxri:jar:1.2.1: Could not transfer artifact javax.jms:jms:jar:1.1 from/to java.net (https://maven-repository.dev.java.net/nonav/repository): Cannot access https://maven-repository.dev.java.net/nonav/repository with type legacy using the available connector factories: BasicRepositoryConnectorFactory: Cannot access https://maven-repository.dev.java.net/nonav/repository with type legacy using the available layout factories: Maven2RepositoryLayoutFactory: Unsupported repository layout legacy -> [Help 1]
```

I started using following log4j (1.2.17) version and it helped me solve this issue without any configurations related fixes.

```
 <dependency>
      <groupId>log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 2):

A check of `ibliblio` and `java.net` repositories reveal that jmx related jar is not present in either. I think you should manually download jms and install them locally as discussed [here](http://www.mail-archive.com/log4j-dev@logging.apache.org/msg07529.html).

Comment: I agree. This solves most of the problems. Browse jarvana.com and for Project field type groupId:artifactId of the jar u are looking for. If you can't find the file, than inspect the pom and try to find out where u can download it from (see downloadUrl here: http://jarvana.com/jarvana/inspect-pom/com/sun/jdmk/jmxtools/1.2.1/jmxtools-1.2.1.pom). Once you download use the following command: mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=groupIdOfJar -DartifactId=artifactIdOfJar -Dversion=versionOfJar -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile="pathToJar.jar" -DgeneratePom=true

Comment: Also check out the different repositories here: http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVENUSER/Mirrors+Repositories
And Maven's mirrors and repositories guide: http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-mirror-settings.html

Answer (score 0):

You import one dependency, and this dependency is dependent on `com.sun.jmx:jmxri:jar:1.2.1` and others, but `com.sun.jmx:jmxri:jar:1.2.1` cannot be found in central repository,

so you'd better try to import another version.

Here suppose your dependency may be log4j, and you can try to import `log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.13`.

Answer (score 0):

May not be the exactly same problem. but there is a nice article on the same line [Here](http://unitstep.net/blog/2009/05/18/resolving-log4j-1215-dependency-problems-in-maven-using-exclusions/)

Comment: Aways best to summarize the article in case the link gets broken