# javaee-api-7.0 with JSF 2.2: f:ajax does not submit

Tags: jsf, java-ee-7

I have a Spring 4.1.1, JSF 2.2.3, Primefaces 5.1 web application that run on Java 8 and Tomcat 8.

Everything worked perfectly until my colleague added the javaee-api-7.0 as a dependency for javax for ActiveMQ.

With this jar in, every ajax call doesn't submit data to the backend. For example filters on primefaces datadatable would always pass an empty value, ajax refresh wouldn't take into account processed fields, etc. If I remove the jar, everything start to work again.

Unfortunately the logs don't show any error, the output is exactly the same of when the jar is not included. I'm not sure also with which component the conflict is, I would assume JSF but I have no clue and I can't find any documentation online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Everything worked perfectly until my colleague added the javaee-api-7.0 as a dependency for javax for ActiveMQ.*

You're indeed not supposed to have that JAR in webapp's runtime classpath. This kind of library is supposed to be already provided by the target Java EE container. Examples of Java EE containers are WildFly, GlassFish, Liberty, TomEE, etc. You've there however Tomcat, which is a barebones servletcontainer supporting from the huge Java EE API only JSP, Servlet and EL APIs, on which you have to manually install every other Java EE artifact, such as JSF and JMS.

The `javaee-api.jar` contains **ALL** Java EE APIs, including the JSF API (which is of 2.2.0 version). In your case, this one apparently got precedence in classloading over the JSF API version which you already had in `/WEB-INF/lib`. This will only result in "odd" behavior, because the loaded JSF impl version doesn't match the loaded JSF API version.

You need to solve it differently. You need to install JMS in its own API/impl JAR files, exactly like as you already did for JSF, and thus absolutely not via a "global" `javaee-api.jar` file. In case of ActiveMQ, the JMS API is available in `activemq-all.jar`. Use that one instead. It covers everything needed in order to get ActiveMQ to run on Tomcat.

#### See also:

- [how to include javax.jms.* in eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9809891/how-to-include-javax-jms-in-eclipse)
- [How do I import the javax.servlet API in my Eclipse project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4076601/how-do-i-import-the-javax-servlet-api-in-my-eclipse-project)