# Cassandra class not found using spark streaming

Tags: java, apache-spark, cassandra, apache-kafka

I am using Spark to get data from kafka and insert it into Cassandra. My program is

```
public static void fetchAndValidateData() {
    SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("name")
            .set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "127.0.0.1")
            .set("spark.cleaner.ttl", "3600");
    JavaStreamingContext jssc = new JavaStreamingContext(sparkConf, new Duration(2000));
    Map<String,String> kafkaParams = new HashMap<>();
    kafkaParams.put("zookeeper.connect", "127.0.0.1");
    kafkaParams.put("group.id", App.GROUP);
    JavaPairReceiverInputDStream<String, EventLog> messages =
            KafkaUtils.createStream(jssc, String.class, EventLog.class, StringDecoder.class, EventLogDecoder.class,
                    kafkaParams, topicMap, StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER_2());
    JavaDStream<EventLog> lines = messages.map(new Function<Tuple2<String, EventLog>, EventLog>() {
        @Override
        public EventLog call(Tuple2<String, EventLog> tuple2) {
            return tuple2._2();
        }
    });
    lines.foreachRDD(rdd -> { javaFunctions(rdd).writerBuilder("test", "event_log", mapToRow(EventLog.class)).saveToCassandra(); });
    jssc.start();
    try {
        jssc.awaitTermination();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    jssc.stop();
    jssc.close();
}
```

My `spark-submit` command is `C:\spark-1.6.2-bin-hadoop2.6\bin\spark-submit --packages org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka_2.10:1.5.2 --class "com.jtv.spark.atnt.App" --master local[4] target\spark.atnt-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar`

My POM file is

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.jtv</groupId>
  <artifactId>spark.atnt</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>spark.atnt</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <build>
    <plugins>  
       <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
          <executions>
              <execution>
                  <phase>package</phase>
                  <goals>
                      <goal>single</goal>
                  </goals>
              </execution>
          </executions>
          <configuration>
              <descriptorRefs>
                  <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
              </descriptorRefs>
          </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.datastax.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-cassandra-connector-java_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
      <artifactId>spark-streaming-kafka_2.11</artifactId>
      <version>1.6.2</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.json-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>0.8.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>0.10.0.1</version>
    </dependency>    
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

I am getting `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.datastax.spark.connector.japi.CassandraJavaUtil` error.

How do I solve it?

---

**Edit:**

I figured out what is causing the problem. It is `org.apache.kafka:kafka_2.10:0.8.0`. When I add `provided` to it, I get the `Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.2-beta-5:single (default) on project spark.atnt: Failed to create assembly: Failed to resolve dependencies for project: com.jtv:spark.atnt:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Could not transfer artifact com.sun.jdmk:jmxtools:jar:1.2.1 from/to java.net (https://maven-repository.dev.java.net/nonav/repository): Cannot access https://maven-repository.dev.java.net/nonav/repository with type legacy using the available connector factories: BasicRepositoryConnectorFactory` error on my `mvn package` command and when I remove it, I get `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.datastax.spark.connector.japi.CassandraJavaUtil` error on my `spark-submit` command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to solve this problem is to package the Cassandra library within your jar file.

In order to do this you can use the maven-assembly-plugin in your pom.xml:

```
       <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

This plugin will package all of your dependencies with your jar file. If you want to prevent some dependencies from being packaged (e.g. spark) you need to add the tag `<scope>provided</scope>`. For example:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Please note that if you use the assembly plugin as described above you will obtain two jar files in your target folder. If you want to use the full jar you will need to run: 
`C:\spark-1.6.2-bin-hadoop2.6\bin\spark-submit --packages org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka_2.10:1.5.2 --class "com.jtv.spark.atnt.App" --master local[4] target\spark.atnt-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar`

Comment: I tried your solution. On running `mvn package`, I am getting `Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.2-beta-5:single (default) on project spark.atnt: Failed to create assembly: Failed to resolve dependencies for project: com.jtv:spark.atnt:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Could not transfer artifact com.sun.jmx:jmxri:jar:1.2.1 from/to java.net (https://maven-repository.dev.java.net/nonav/repository): Cannot access https://maven-repository.dev.java.net/nonav/repository with type legacy using the available connector factories: BasicRepositoryConnectorFactory` error.

Comment: It looks like you might have a problem similar to this stackoverflow question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4908651/the-following-artifacts-could-not-be-resolved-javax-jmsjmsjar1-1

Comment: Remember to set `<scope>provided</scope>` for the dependecies you don't need in your target jar file. e.g. anything in the group `org.apache.spark`

Comment: I figured out what is causing the problem. It is `org.apache.kafka:kafka_2.10:0.8.0`. When I add `provided` to it, I get the `Cannot access https://maven-repository.dev.java.net/nonav/repository with type legacy using the available connector factories: BasicRepositoryConnectorFactory` and when I remove it, I get `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.datastax.spark.connector.japi.CassandraJavaUtil`.