# What happened to JMS 1.1 in Maven Central?

Tags: maven, jms

It seems that the jar is missing.

```
~ => wget http://central.maven.org/maven2/javax/jms/jms/1.1/jms-1.1.jar
--2017-11-27 11:22:29--  http://central.maven.org/maven2/javax/jms/jms/1.1/jms-1.1.jar
Resolving central.maven.org... 151.101.40.209
Connecting to central.maven.org|151.101.40.209|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2017-11-27 11:22:29 ERROR 404: Not Found.
```

[image]

Comment: Please have a look at this [Stackoverflow post on missing JMS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5272660/672586)

Comment: thanks, it seems they have a ticket for it too https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/MVNCENTRAL-348 - licensing issues

Answer (score 3):

It seems that jms 1.1 has been removed from maven central long time ago because of licensing issues, look [here](https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/MVNCENTRAL-348)