# Getting "Failed to capture snapshot of input files for task ':compileJava' "

Tags: java, gradle, apache-kafka, jms

i am trying to setup a simple gradle project for Apache Kafka POC. Please suggest how to resolve this.

stacktrace while building

---

```
Root cause: org.gradle.internal.resolve.ArtifactNotFoundException: Could not find jms.jar (javax.jms:jms:1.1).
Searched in the following locations:
    https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax/jms/jms/1.1/jms-1.1.jar
```

---

This is the gradle file used for the project

---

```
apply plugin: 'java-library'


repositories {

     mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    api 'org.apache.commons:commons-math3:3.6.1'

    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:23.0'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'

    compile(group: 'org.apache.kafka', name: 'kafka_2.10', version: '0.8.0') 

    compile 'org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:0.10.2.0'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is coming from the transitive library *log4j-1.2.15* which belongs to *zookeeper* transitive libraries:

```
    +--- org.apache.kafka:kafka_2.10:0.8.0
|    +--- org.apache.zookeeper:zookeeper:3.3.4
|    |    +--- log4j:log4j:1.2.15
|    |    |    +--- javax.mail:mail:1.4
|    |    |    |    \--- javax.activation:activation:1.1
|    |    |    +--- javax.jms:jms:1.1
|    |    |    +--- com.sun.jdmk:jmxtools:1.2.1
|    |    |    \--- com.sun.jmx:jmxri:1.2.1
|    |    \--- jline:jline:0.9.94
|    |         \--- junit:junit:3.8.1
```

This *log4j* version has dependencies on other libraries which are not hosted on maven central repository (see [What happened to JMS 1.1 in Maven Central?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47518359/what-happened-to-jms-1-1-in-maven-central))

So you can add *jcenter()* repository

```
repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
}
```

But then you will have other issues with other transitive libs that you should exclude : either exclude *log4j* or *jdmk* and *jmx* from transitive dependencies as follows:

```
dependencies {
    api 'org.apache.commons:commons-math3:3.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:23.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'

    compile(group: 'org.apache.kafka', name: 'kafka_2.10', version: '0.8.0'){
        exclude group : "com.sun.jdmk"
        exclude group : "com.sun.jmx"

        // or simply exclude all  log4j:
        //  exclude group : "log4j"
    }
    compile 'org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:0.10.2.0'
}
```

Mode details about issue with *log4j 1.2.15*  :http://unitstep.net/blog/2009/05/18/resolving-log4j-1215-dependency-problems-in-maven-using-exclusions/